# Prevent HTML/JS injection with Javascript or CSS

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

I am trying to create some sort of chatting program with JS and node.js is there anyway to prevent  `<script>alert("injection");</script>` to be injected on the client side which is 100% secure? (without the use of regex). Otherwise what would be the best node.js solution?

Comment: Escape all `<` and `>`.

Comment: will that be enough? also how would you do this?

Comment: If you are just trying to simply display the text safely on the client side, changing all `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&rt;` should be enough. However it doesn't cover injections on your server or if you determine HTML attributes depending on their inputs.

Comment: `&rt` should be `&gt`

Comment: have a look at https://www.npmjs.org/package/htmlstrip-native